# Debugging does not Work with LG G3 Phone

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a Xamarin Android App and
my Visual Studio 2015 does not recognize LG G3 Phone. 
I use Windows 8.1 in a Virtual Machine.
I updated the Driver on my Windndows 8.1 for the LG G3,
I Enabled Developer Options and USB Debugging(on the Phone). I did the same with Samsung Galxy S4 GT-I9505 and it worked.
It appears in Visual Studio under Start Debugging: List of Emulators and the galaxy S4 is there.
What could be the Problem with LG G3 ?

Thanks!

Comment: the LG G3 has Version 4.4.2 and Project v4.0 and upper

Comment: If you type in cmd 'adb devices' can you see your g3?

Comment: I solved the Problem by installing LGUnitedMobileDriver_S52MAN314AP22_ML_WHQL_Ver_3.14.1.exe Driver